# How to populate date input in Angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular, date, input, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormGroup that takes date from a date input.

FormControl:

```
dob: new FormControl(new Date()),
```

Assigning new Date() to get the default date, in case no date is selected.

Template:

```
<input type="date" formControlName="dob">
```

However, when I am using **patchValue** to populate the date (from a previously persisted object), it is not workning/showing up in the date input tag's text (in the webpage). What am I missing?

Comment: a input type date manage "strings"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should format the date using `formatDate` function form `@angular/common` namespace before the patch or initialize.

E.g: `dob: new FormControl(formatDate(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd", "en"))`

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-beeloy?file=src/app/app.component.ts).